# Convert MongoDB BsonDocument into a string

Tags: serialization, mongodb, document, mongodb-.net-driver

How do a convert an entire MongoDB BsonDocument into a string?

(I'm using the official C# driver)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can convert BsonDocument into a JSON formatted string using [`MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/8edc0d16-6676-7936-c8d0-05e4192e2c0e.htm).

Comment: You need to call the extension method with options to generate valid json: ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict })

Comment: I realize @BlakeNiemyjski wrote this a little while ago, but could someone elaborate on where the BsonDocument that you're going to convert would go in Blake's example?

Comment: What do you mean by go? You'd get the BsonDocument from the .Net Mongo Driver.

Answer (score 7):

Code used shown below:

```
string rc = responseDoc.ToJson<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>();
```