# Convert Bson to string - MongoDB/Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, mongodb, bson

how do I convert a bson obj to a string?
I read [Convert MongoDB BsonDocument into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937665/convert-mongodb-bsondocument-into-a-string) but that's for c#.
I'm using Javascript for Mongodb

It would be applied at something like this:

```
myvar = db.mycol.stats();
```

Comment: Is this in the `mongo` shell?

Comment: That is a javascript the I run with:  mongo server:port/mydb --quiet /path/myscript.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `tojson` function like so:

```
str = tojson(db.mycol.stats());
```